# Returning 11 while I am not returning anything

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int increment(int i)
{
    if(i<=10)
    {
        cout<<i;
        i++;
        increment(i);

    }
    //return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<increment(0);
}
```

It is printing 11 too when I am not returning anything, why do you think it is?

Comment: Turn up your warning level. For gcc, for example, use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `increment` function is declared as returning `int` but you're not returning anything. Your compiler should absolutely be generating a warning.

If you're using GCC, you should always specify *at least* `-Wall`. I prefer `-Wextra`, and `-Werror` will convert these warnings to errors, so the compilation actually fails. See [GCC Warning Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

---

What's *actually* happening? The ABI / [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for many architectures specify a particular CPU register to hold the return value of a function. (On x86 this is `eax`, and on ARM this is `r0`.)  Since you have no `return` statement in your function, the compiler is not going to put any value in that register as the return value before the function returns. Whatever value *happened to be* in that register is what the calling function will see as the return value.

Answer (score 1):

In the calling conventions for most processors there is a register used to return values that fit in a native register word.  The calling conventions also specify which registers are "caller saves" (can be changed without being saved by a function) and "callee saves" (which must either go unused or be saved and restored by a function).  The return register is naturally a "caller saves" kind of register because it will be modified by the function to return a value.  This means that during the body of a function it is likely to be chosen as a scratch register.  In your case, the register gets used for `i` and since there is no explicit return to modify that register, it is still set to 11 when the function returns to the caller.